# How to assign struct values to other struct values using bitwise operations?

Tags: c, struct, bit-manipulation

I have a struct as below

```
struct A
{
  char x;
  int y;
  short z;
}a;

struct B
{
  char ch;
}b;

struct C
{
  int in;
}c;

struct D
{
  short sho;
}d;
```

I have to assign (a.x to b.ch), (a.y to c.in), (a.z to d.sho) only by using bitwise manipulations.

Can you please help?

Comment: Because the assignment operator is too mainstream ?

Comment: ;-) No, because doing one's own homework is too mainstream.

Answer (score 0):

For any a and x (with equal bit length):

```
x = ((a & x) | x)
```

Comment: Can you Please answer in the context which I have asked. Please?

Comment: I mean for the same example. and using the same variables.

Comment: sadly he appears to be only allowed &, | or !. At least, if he's quoted his homework assignment right. You're using =

Comment: that is for mathematical equivalence. An assignment seems inevitable though.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible, you cannot assign anything using the bitwise operators and your task does not make any sense. (The operators |= &= etc are not bitwise operators, they are assignment operators, see C11 6.5.16.)

Furthermore, you should not write code like `a & 0x00FFFFFFFF` and expect to mask out variable a.y, because the compiler is free to add any number of padding bytes anywhere inside a struct.

Comment: for your last statement you can anyway not perform bitwise operations on objects of structure types.

Comment: @ouah You can do anything in C, if you are desperate/dumb enough. `*(unsigned long long*)&a & 0x00FFFFFFFFu`. Really, really bad code.